# How to Convert shapefile into map file?

Tags: maps, shapefile, file-conversion

I have shapefiles for mapping. I need to convert that shapefile into map file. Please help me to convert the shapefile into map file? Thanks in Advance!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to take a couple of steps here.

First, convert it to a .osm, then to a .pbf and finally to a map file.

Refer to [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Shapefile) for converting to OSM.

As for the pbf use [Osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) to do that.

Then use [Mapsforge](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/downloads/detail?name=mapsforge-map-writer-0.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar&can=2&q=) to finalise the process.

Hope this helps!

Rachel